# Get Response From WebView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I load web view with parameter and web view load successful, and when doing something in web view i will get response from webView.
there is my code for load web view :

```
func loadWebView() {
        let param ="&nc=" + nc + "&token=" + token        
        let url = URL(string: "http://www.****.**/payment/payment.php?" + param)!
        let request = NSURLRequest(url: url)

        webView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
        webView.reload()
}
```

when payment in web view is not successful i should get this response :

http://www.*****.**/payment/result_false.php?error=Canceled%20By%20User

when payment in web view is successful i should get this response :

http://www.*****.**/payment/result_true.php?refid=25861481459291

this response is url how can get this from web view?

Comment: You need to use the delegate to the webview so that you can use the webViewDidFinishLoad method.

Comment: @ElTomato thanks for your response this work well but how can for example get error=Canceled from this url :http://www.*****.**/payment/result_false.php?error=Canceled%20By%20User

Comment: have you found any solutions yet ?

Comment: @FadyLateef if you want link to  your app from webView you can use this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41891144/return-from-safari-to-ios-application-with-uialertview