# Return from Safari to IOS application with UIAlertView

Tags: ios, swift, safari, uialertcontroller

I opened a link in safari browser, its a web page for online Payment, I want to do is that when user press cancel button on webPage then it will show alert view in safari and come back to application and when user press ok then it open iOS application again, I do not have any reviews for this. I need help about this.

Comment: If your application is supposed to support  iOS 9 onwards then check Universal links. If you are supporting iOS 8 onwards then check deeplinking only (Custom URL SCHEMES)

Comment: Please check deep linking concept. i hope this will solve your requirement

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan for using Universal links, application must be uploaded on iTunes?

Comment: no there is no such restriction

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan in my case when user tap cancel button in website i should get /payment/result_false.php , is this the app that should be added to /apple-app-site-association file ?

Comment: @Muhammad Adnan for using universal links server should support https ? what capability we need for using universal link in server side ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html Upload the apple-app-site-association file to your HTTPS web server. You can place the file at the root of your server or in the .well-known subdirectory. Thats it and configure your app id and appdomains cabability in iOS project. One thing to be noted is your redirection link will be opened in browser with an open on banner to open in app . you will not be redirected to app directly without user's interaction